# Sour Dough Wet Dough

Tags: baking, bread, dough

I have made many loaves of bread, but I just got my starter done for my first Sour Dough loaf.  I’m following a recipe to the letter, and am now in the kneading phase, my question is that the dough is still quite sticky, it seems like it is working well between kneading, but is a bit difficult to handle. Can I give it a light dusting of flour before kneading to make handling a bit easier?